# How can I download a video off Safari 9.1? (not YouTube)

Tags: safari, macos

How can I download a video off of Safari 9.1 and export it into iMovie?
The video is not from YouTube.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the video you want to download, please.

Comment: Some sites where download is not licensed use pretty sneaky ways to prevent download.  I think there is no one way that works for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [keepvid](http://keepvid.com), which has support for many sites. All you have to do is enter the URL for the site containing the video, and choose the output you want. You can also choose to get the video or audio only, and this does work for YouTube.

This works with almost all modern browsers, no extension required.

Answer (score 0):

On http://savefrom.net/ , there is an extension (SaveFrom Helper) you can download which will allow you to save at full quality any video on the Internet, being from YouTube or not. It supports ***Safari***, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, any Chromium browser that IS NOT Google Chrome and more